# How to display typeahead.js dropdown data on button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a way to make use of [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput) library with [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) to a create a tagging input field with combo box functionality. So then the user can see the available items without getting it when typing.

I'm in the beginning of creating it and so far I was able to run the `tags-input` with `typeahead` safely. So now it will show all its data when the text field get focused.

Later I found that it's happening by triggering the `focus` function of it. But I can't trigger it the way I tried to.

How can I show the dropdown list after a button click event happens?

This is my code so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#device').tagsinput({
          typeahead: {
            source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo'],
            autoSelect: false,
            showHintOnFocus : true,
            minLength : 0
          }
    });

    $('#myButton').click(function() {
       $(".typeahead").trigger("focus");  // wont work
    });

});
</script> 

<div class="container">
<div class="bs-example">
    City : <input id="device" ></input>
    <button id="myButton" >Show</button>
</div>  
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by trigger `keyup` on the hidden `<input>` element :

```js
$('#device').tagsinput({
   typeahead: {
     source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo', 'Berlin', 'Stockholm', 'Copenhagen' ],
     autoSelect: false,
     minLength : 0
   }
});     
//trigger the typeahead
$('#myButton').click(function() { 
   $(".bootstrap-tagsinput input").val('');
   $(".bootstrap-tagsinput input").trigger('keyup');
});
```

The only "but" here is : You must comment out one line [`#408`] in the typeahead source to prevent it from closing on mouseover, due to the mismatch between `focused` and `shown` that occured when we tricked the typeahead to open :

```js
mouseleave: function (e) {
  this.mousedover = false;
  //if (!this.focused && this.shown) this.hide(); <-- line #408
}
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/TU7HUS49mck7BMJhMd1B?p=preview**

---

Trick to have "unlimited" items with scrollable menu :

```
.dropdown-menu {
    overflow-y : scroll;
    max-height: 250px !important;
}
```

in options

```
items : 1000,
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/7yDk829M3wavyn1oJoAE?p=preview**
[image]

Comment: I managed to do this by triggering the `focus()` to the input tag added by the tagsinput.
`$("#id-of-the-input-added-by-tags-input").focus();` But your suggestion is worth looking.

Comment: Since you are familiar with this :) is there a way to avoid the dropdown data getting sorted according to natural order ?
and here only limited number of data is showing. How can I show all the data in the source inside dropdown list.

Comment: @prime - Have heavily edited the answer, I actually believed you would use typeahead.js, but you were already on the good old 2.x typeahead track, did not follow the link in the question :(

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead and
https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput. it is okay right ?

Comment: @prime, yes - the same I has in the plunkr.

Comment: @prime, see update. Cannot figure out to use the sorter right now, a little bit weird - but you can easily have many, many items ... Have to leave now, it is late and I have 1½ hour transport time home...

Comment: Did you try `items:-1` . coz I just tried it and looks like it also works.

Answer (score 1):

Does `$(".typeahead").focus();` not work?

Comment: I managed to do this by triggering the focus() to the input tag added by the tagsinput. $("#id-of-the-input-added-by-tags-input").focus();

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way that worked for me:

```
$(document).on('click','.typeahead', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "" ) {
        $(this).trigger("input");
    }
});
```